# Semantically / Best Practice for formatting data in HTML5

Tags: html, semantics

I've been trying to find the most correct way to format random sets of data using HTML.

In my particular case, I have something like:

```
John Johnson
20K Service Due
2000 Honda Civic
```

It's not a paragraph, so wrapping each line in `<p>` tags doesn't seem correct.

It's not a list, so using `<ul>` and wrapping each line in `<li>` tags doesn't seem correct.

Placing the content inside a `<div>` and then using `<br>`s after each line works but still doesn't seem like it's the best.

The data is similar to an address, which if it was, I could do something like:

```html
<address>
  John Johnson<br>
  20K Service Due<br>
  2000 Honda Civic
</address>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply pushing data to the screen and want to "know" what format the data is then maybe you can tag each element with the "data" attribute and set a value to it before you push it to the dom.  Once you set the data attribute (e.g. data-format) to any value you like, you can than use CSS to format it and you can use JavaScript to manipulate it as well based on the value you set.

```js
let data_format = document.querySelectorAll('[data-format]')
data_format.forEach((element) => {
    console.log(`Data Format = ${element.dataset.format}`)
})
```

```html
<div>
    <li data-format="name">John Johnson</li>
    <li data-format="service-date">20K Service Due</li>
    <li data-format="model">2000 Honda Civic</li>
</div>
```

Comment: That's an invalid HTML

Comment: @AlonEitan how is it invalid html?  You can add data attributes to just about anything, yes?  https://www.dofactory.com/html/li/data

Comment: It's fine after your last edit ( You can't have a `li` element as a child of `div`)